# 404 when WordPress is in a subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this question often comes up but none of the answers is satisfactory for me. I tried everything I could find on the web nothing works.

1 - I installed my Wordpress in a sub folder `/folder/wp`.

2 - I moved `.htaccess` and `index.php` to the root ( given by WordPress )

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

3 - I changed `index.php` like this:

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

4 - I changed WordPress url: http://localhost/folder/wp

5 - I kept site url: http://localhost/folder

Without Permalinks, everything works.
As soon as I turn on permalinks, I have a 404

There are some things I do not understand:

1 - Why keep `index.php` and `.htaccess` in the sub folder?

2 - Some say to add `/wp` in RewriteBase and RewriteRule in `.htaccess` at the root, but it does not change?

I read dozens of Post and nothing works for me. Has anyone ever faced this problem?

thank you very much

Comment: Please notice item number 7 at the `CODEX` instructions here https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory which says you need to copy not move your `.htaccess` and `index.php`  (your item 2 above).

Comment: I saw and it's done. But wordpress never change the .htaccess in the subfolder, so is always empty.

Comment: is rewrite module enabled? have you added <Directory /path/to/root>
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
        </Directory> to virtual host?

Comment: is the directory executable permission enabled?

Comment: Thanks Coder anonymous, this is it!!! http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: http://blog.drinkncode.com/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-php-yii-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that is not thought is to ensure that the Apache mod_rewrite module is enabled. There are dozens of tutorials on Wordpress installation in a sub folder but none specifies that. I hope this can help.